# Sylius/FriendsOfSymfony: What is a "token" Grant Type?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, sylius

[The documentation for Sylius's REST API](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/api/authorization.html) indicates its oAuth authorization system supports three grant types.

```
php bin/console sylius:oauth-server:create-client \
    --grant-type="password" \
    --grant-type="refresh_token" \
    --grant-type="token"
```

The `password` grant type allows you to fetch a token from `/api/oauth/v2/token` using your admin username and password (assuming that user has the `ROLE_API_ACCESS` role).

When you fetch this token, it comes down with an `access_token` and a  `refresh_token`.

```
{
    "access_token":"ODE0NzA2NmU1NGVkNDc5ODNiNjcxZDBhZTA0NGY3MzY4NjBlMTc3ZDk0ZjM3MTIyOTlkMTQzMWU3YjM3ODc5ZQ",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "scope":null,
    "refresh_token":"NjNlNGY1YTQ5NmJhMzZiNzdlY2JmMzQyZDc5MGZkYTA5Mzg4MDc2MmRmZTRmOWE0MmMwNzU4NzBmMGM3YzVmZQ"
}
```

When your token expires, if your client has the `refresh_token` grant type, you can use the `/api/oauth/v2/token` endpoint to fetch a new token using the `refresh_token` parameter/argument.

So what is a `token` grant type?  When I think about this, I get stuck on "How could you fetch a token from `/api/oauth/v2/token` if you don't have a token in the first place?" or "If you already HAD a token that hadn't expired why would you need to use `token` to get a new one?"

So what am I missing?  What is the token grant-type for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several grant types provided by OAuth2.  [See them here](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/).  I'm not sure exactly which one is used by sylius when you ask for `"token"` but I assume authorization code.

```
The most common OAuth 2.0 grant types are listed below.

   Authorization Code
   Implicit
   Password
   Client Credentials
   Device Code
   Refresh Token
```

Comment: "token" corresponds with the "implicit" grant type: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/oauth2-php/blob/master/lib/OAuth2.php#L234

Comment: Thank you -- that link to the spec was what I needed!